# Effective ways to represent logical expression

Tags: boolean, language-agnostic, expression, logical-or

I am writing a console program to represent logical expressions( something likes `AB'C + A'C`) so that I can be simplify( optimize) the expressions and evaluate their values. I tried to use `string` to represent an expression, but in this way, I can only evaluate its value base on input values, but optimize an expression that  represented as string is very difficult( with me), Example, `ABC + AB` can be `AB` because `ABC+AB` = `AB(C+1)` = `AB`. I have also think another way it is using `vector of vector of literal`. Example, `AB'C + AB + BC` will be represent as below figure:

[image]

Explaining: Each column is represent for each term, in above example. The first column represents for `AB'C`, the second one represents for `AB` and the third one represents for `BC'`. 
I think it is a good way to present logical expression but I still can not find a way to optimize an expression that repression by this way. I also googled but I did not find sample project for the problem.

In short, I hope someone suggest to me a way to represent, evaluate and optimize an logical expression easier. Thank in advance!

Comment: I like your presentation of the problem - but you haven't shown your code or what problem you have. Also, java and c++ as tags ...?
A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, before writing code, I need to determine my problem, what data structure need to be used and more. So I have no code here.

Comment: You also need to pick a language.

Comment: OK, I deleted `java` tag. But what I need is a way to represent an logical expression, not for any specific language.

Comment: @Ayxan, No. I am mentioning to `logical expression`. Each literal can only be `false` or `true`.

Comment: @TaQuangTu Does `C+1 = 1` mean `(something boolean) || true = true` ?

Comment: @Hiroki yes! it is!

Comment: You appear to be asking us to do your homework for you.  If this is not correct, please [edit] your question to be far more specific about where you are having problems.

Comment: @JoeC it is not my homework, I just wanna find the most effective way to represent a logical expression on memory so that I can easy to evaluate value, optimize it. The problem is int optimizing, it is very difficult if we can not find a suitable data structure and I think my question is clearly.

Comment: Does `struct ta {uint16_t v:2};` and `std::vector<std::vector<ta>> m;` work? I selected a type larger than `char` to make it easy to print the values, but if you don't need it, go for a smaller type.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have not write any code, I must determine the most effective data structure to represent an logical expression, with each data structure that I mentioned, I still can not find a way to optimize the expression that represented bt the data structure, it is big problem for me. So, I wanna emphasize that what I need is a effective data structure, not fixing my code!

Comment: What I proposed _was_ a way to represent the logical expression as you presented it. I suggest that you first solve the problem and then try to optimize your solution - not the other way around.

Comment: @TaQuangTu What does your `'` mean ? Is that a logical operator ? Is `AB'C` not equal to `ABC` ?

Comment: @Hiroki if B is true then B' be false, if B is false then B' is true.

Comment: Which operators do you support? AND (no symbol), OR (+), NOT (') so far. Any more ((in-)equality, ...)? What about parenthesising? Variable names are always single characters?

Comment: `You also need to pick a language.` You are correct in picking the data structure first.

Comment: Of interest: YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knc95V6ynHU) explaining the simplification of `AB+ABC` to `AB`

Answer (score 1):

> How to represent, evaluate and optimize a logical expression?

To represent this you need to use an expression tree and since you are using only logic operators that are binary operators you want to use a [binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) or more specifically [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree#Boolean_expressions).

To simplify the tree you use the laws of [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Laws).

If all of the values are bound, then through the process of simplification the tree will simplify to a root node with either `true` or `false`.

For some example code I checked [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) but they had no task for evaluating Boolean expressions. The closest task is [arithmetic evaluation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arithmetic_evaluation).

Comment: Oh thank Guy Coder! I also try using binary expression tree. With this way, it is easy to get value of an expression but it is hard to optimize. I have writing an ExpressionTree before https://github.com/TaQuangTu/ExpressionTreeC-/blob/master/ExpressionTree.h. Maybe I need to try more and more with the second way( Using vector to represent expressions)!

Comment: @TaQuangTu Just because it is hard for you and you don't understand it doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: I don't accept the answer at this point, I just voted up for your question because it is helpful for someone else, not me now! I used to think about the same way you gave me and i have written code. I realized it is simple to get value of an expression but hard to optimize it. Anyway, Thanks for your answer!